# Android How to play audio for 2 times before moving to the next one

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I want to play the audio two times before playing the next item.

This is my class where I want to display the items.

```
    public void startSlides() {

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Intent intent = getIntent();

                    int setId = intent.getIntExtra("SelectedSetId",0);

                    databaseAccess.open();

                    setId = setId + 1;

                    List<byte[]> audio = databaseAccess.getAudioA(setId);

                    if (i > audio.size()){
                        i = 0;
                    }else{
                        playAudio(audio.get(i));

                        playAudio(audio.get(i));
                        i++;}

                    List<String> vocab = databaseAccess.getVocabNameA(setId);
                    textView2.setText(vocab.get(k));
                    k++;

                    textView.setText(+j + "/" + vocab.size());
                    j++;

                    databaseAccess.close();

                    if (j == vocab.size() + 1) {
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }, 0, DURATION);

}
```

I think I have to add something at the playAudio(audio.get(i)), but I have no idea how should I do. If I do this, it plays the audio at the same time. Thanks.

```
    if (i > audio.size()){
                        i = 0;
                    }else{
                        playAudio(audio.get(i));

                        playAudio(audio.get(i));
                        i++; }
```